# Ajax Pagination with Jquery, PHP, Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pagination

I am looking for a good ajax pagination tutorial that uses jQuery, PHP, and MySQL. The ones that I have come across are not good.

So, if anyone could recommend a good site/tutorial that would be great. thanks.

**Edit**
Here are some tutorials that were not good.

[Site 1](http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/20/ajax-pagination-with-jqueryphpmysql/)

[Site 2](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html)

[Site 3](http://www.phpjquery.com/jquery-tutorial/pagination-with-jquery-and-php/)

Comment: Make the pagination working without JS and add the Ajax behavior later. This way, your site also works without JS.

Comment: Better Ajax Pagination http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html

Comment: Srinivas is too aggressive on getting subscriber, one has too subscribe to download his attachment and he will not show everything on the page. You know people can just unsubscribe after? Why forcing people to read about your stuff when you can prove it FIRST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one tutorial from **[CakePHP](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/easy-ajax-pagination-using-jquery)**.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with CakePHP.

Comment: Start here:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/4/Beginning-With-CakePHP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe little bit off-topic, but here is some interesting read from **Jeff Atwood** (founder of stackoverflow) about **the end of pagination**. I really agree with him that you should look at why you are paginating and if it's really necessary. **[Please check this link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/the-end-of-pagination.html)**.