# How do I limit an already limited query?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I limit a query that is already limited?

The thing is, I'm dividing the results into pages, and in my case, this is also done by `LIMIT` (is there really any other way to do it...?), so using LIMIT again seems to be impossible. Obviously, if you have any ideas on how this can be done in PHP instead (simple code, please), do post it.

Comment: For what reason would you want to limit your resultset? why not just lower the LIMIT in your sql query itself?

Comment: Like Brad mentions, I want to save resources.

Comment: you'd be saving resources by not querying any rows past row x.. if you then limit the set of results within your php script, you'll already have used the mysql resources. or am i mistaken?

Answer (score 6):

Use an Offset

e.g.

`[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]`

see the [Select Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

The offset would be calculated by doing something like this

```
$offset = ($page-1) * $pagesize
```

The select would then be

```
SELECT 
     ...
   FROM
      yourtable
   LIMIT 
      $offset, $pagesize
```

Comment: This isn't what I want to do. This just fetches a specific amount of results for one page. What I want to do is limit everything that is fetched. Let's say normally, a query like yours would fetch 10 results on 10 pages. What I want to do is limit the query so it results in less than 10 pages (by fetching less results, ofcourse).

Comment: So you want to fetch 100 rows to begin with? then its just `LIMIT 100`  or `LIMIT $pagesize * $pagecount`

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to divide the results into pages. You see, my query looks like this for each page: `LIMIT $ResultsPerPage * $CurrentPage, $Offset`.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you're looking for is pagination. Check out [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178297/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php-mysql) for some good tutorial recommendations.

In short, you should be able to create a function that takes a limit and an offset and build your query from that.

Comment: I'm not looking for pagination. It has already been done, I just want to limit a query, and then divide the limited query into pages (and again, pagination has already been done).

Comment: Why don't you just change your limit, then? Or run a count on the query first, and if it returns more than a certain threshold, change the limit to reflect the desired limit? You might get better answers if you clarify in your question what, exactly, you're looking to do (examples help!) and perhaps even *why* you're looking to do it.