# jQuery Pagination from data loaded with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to incorporate a jQuery Pagination plugin for data that's been generated from PHP/MySQL.

My question is about the page load and which executes first.  The jQuery is all in a `$(document).ready(function()` and it doesn't seem to be interacting with the content that is loaded from the PHP/mySQL.

Which loads first, the PHP/MySQL or the jQuery?  Is there a better AJAX way to accomplish the pagination?

Here's a fiddle of the plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/jzqu8/3/

Comment: can we get some java script and php?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to put it in a fiddle.

Comment: Updated.  I didn't get too complex.  The PHP generates fine.  It's the pagination plugin that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either load your first data set with php/mysql (page 1) on the page prior to setting up the jquery pagination OR you can forgo with the initial page 1 of data loading and load the first page from an init ajax call afterwards.

related: [Ajax Pagination with Jquery, PHP, Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178297/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php-mysql)