# Creating pagination with ajax results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

In all the time I've spent developing, one thing I've never really understood is the proper way to create "pagination" with AJAX search results.

So, I'm returning 40 results and I want to be able to paginate them by 10 at a time ... is it a matter of spitting them out on the page, adding some css classes and hiding/showing each group of 10 at a time?

Can someone point me in the direction of some "from scratch" pagination?

Comment: If you use ajax, why don't you just return the 10 results you need?

Comment: Google is your friend. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178297/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php-mysql?rq=1

Comment: Because the user needs to be aware that there are more than 10 results, and I shouldn't have to query the DB again for 11-20. And @chris, no, Google is not my friend in this case. Too many crap results. And that link you have there is pointless. I'm not using any frameworks.

Comment: In that case it is the same as non-ajax pagination.

Comment: why you want to query maxmum data at same time and then loading on DOM; I think paginatin technique of fetching with limit Works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far and away the easiest way to do it is to use a canned script.  I recommend [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net), which will do all the paging for you, or if you choose can do it via individual ajax calls to PHP.  At it's simplest, you'd spit out a valid table of results with a `<thead>`, call `$(element).datatables()` and you'd be done.

IF you HAVE to do it from scratch, it's a matter of returning a set number of results from your database, making a call with a start and end number for the record (or a start number and number of rows to return)  Then you would build buttons or links that change that view by passing different parameters to the server and receiving data back.  Ajax would be preferable so you don't need to reload the page each time.

`[CEIL][2]` is your friend for determining pages for the navigation.

If you chose to do it without hitting the database each time (a notion improved in Datatables by a process called "pipelining") then you'd spit out divs of information based on the amount to display, then show and hide them based on the page you want to be on.  It wouldn't work for huge datasets (too much to the dom and too long to load) plus it won't be pretty to write, either.

Comment: Can't I do it without query the DB again and again? Just spit out the results and group them within a `tabs` like structure?

Comment: See edit.  Again, Datatables or another grid is by FAR the way to go.

Comment: DataTables looks amazing. Let it be known that this is exactly why I post questions like this on SO. Thanks a ton!